# Loading Environment Variables in java through the Ant script

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, environment-variables, jibx

I'm using jibx to convert a xml to JAVA and vice versa.  Here, in an Ant script, I'm using the following code to load the `JIBX_HOME` path from the environment variable:

```xml
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="jibx-home" value="${env.JIBX_HOME}"/>
```

I have set the `JIBX_HOME` environment variable to `.bashrc` as follows:

```sh
export JIBX_HOME=/rezsystem/jibx_1_2_2/jibx
```

But this path is not loaded to the jibx-home property. 
When I simply type `$ set command` in the terminal it prints. `JIBX_HOME=/rezsystem/jibx_1_2_2/jibx` successfully.  What have I missed here? My OS is Ubuntu 12.10 and my IDE is Eclipse kepler.

Comment: Are you using eclipse with a different user? Can you try other methods to set environmental variables mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables.

Comment: Yes there are two user accounts in my machine. Admin and myAccount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add the line to the current bashrc
like, key in on a shell,

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

then enter the line at the end,

```
export JIBX_HOME=/rezsystem/jibx_1_2_2/jibx
```

don't use sudo command, save the file and restart the system.

Answer (score 2):

I think you also have to add your environment variable with PATH also

like:

```
export JIBX_HOME=/rezsystem/jibx_1_2_2/jibx

export PATH=$PATH:$JIBX_HOME
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  print out the environment property using echo then is it set properly?

Ant properties are immutable anyway so you can just remove the entire not condition as you can't override the jibx-home property using your condition.

Comment: Thank you quotidian. I have put the script as it was in the code I modified. I have removed the condition to make it much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Try running eclipse with:

```
    bash -ic "path to eclipse"
```

Do this after exporting JIBX_HOME variable.

I had to change my link to eclipse to this because it was not loading all env variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting these environment variables in your `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: Currently when I print the environment variables, it prints a lot of variables. But not the one I set in the .bashrc. There's no .bash_profile file in all accounts

Comment: So, create one. This should work. Just `cat >> ~/.bash_profile` and paste your vars in there.